# Looking for shortcut to combine selectize and textInput

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a bit complex CRUD interface for databases (create, read, update and delete) (probably shiny is not the best tool for this, but I wanna give it a try since I'm not familiar with js). I've already found some nice examples, specially the one from [Barbara](https://github.com/bborgesr/wsds2017). Now I'm looking for a shortcut to combine a `selectizeInput` and a `textInput` (maybe as an option of selectize?!), because otherwise my code gets so long if I have to do it like the following examples shows. The example shall demonstrate what I wanna get. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768785/shiny-update-input-text-for-select-input) is not what I'm looking for.)

Here's a very short reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
startData <- c("Berlin", "London", "Paris")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("town", "Town", choices = c(startData, "new town")),
  uiOutput("newTown")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rV <- reactiveValues(towns = startData)

   output$newTown <- renderUI({
     if (input$town == "new town") {
       tagList(
         textInput("text", "New Town"),
         actionButton("entry", "save town")
       )
     }
   })
   # update selectizeInput when actionButton is clicked
   observeEvent(input$entry, {
     rV$towns <- c(rV$towns, input$text)
     updateSelectizeInput(
       session, "town", "Town",
       choices = c(rV$towns, "new town"),
       selected = input$text
     )
   })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For a bit more complex example, I tried to implement a simple datatable to edit which you can find on my [github](https://github.com/frumentum/combineInputs) account. Hopefully there's a shorter way doing so...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, a **selectize** input is already a combination of `textInput` and `selectInput`. And as such, the desired functionality is already included in the selectize package. You can pass option arguments to the `selectizeInput`, which will be directly translated to the JavaScript package. [See here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) for a list of options.

One of those is the **create** option that specifies if and when an option can be created by just typing something that does not match any given choice.

The whole server code in the following example can be omitted to show this, but I left some evaluations in there to clarify how to actually broaden the set of choices once created by the framework.

```
library(shiny)
startData <- c("Berlin", "London", "Paris")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("town", "Town", choices = startData, options=list(create=TRUE))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rV <- reactiveValues(towns = startData)

  observeEvent(input$town, {
    # nchar check, because emptying the text field results in "" choice.
    if (nchar(input$town) && !(input$town %in% rV$towns)) {
      rV$towns <- c(rV$towns, input$town)
    }

    print(rV$towns)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```